# Rails 4 devise sessions controller override routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have overrided devise's session controller, but now when i am trying to hit this link locally localhost:3000/users/sign_in, i am running into the following error,

```
 ActionController::RoutingError (undefined local variable or method `users' for main:Object)      
 app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

till now I have this much of code in my sessions controller  :

```
class users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
 before_filter :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

 def new
  super
 end

 def create
  self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
  set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  if !session[:return_to].blank?
   redirect_to session[:return_to]
   session[:return_to] = nil
  else
   respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
 end

 def destroy
  super
 end


 def configure_sign_in_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) << :attribute
 end
end
```

and I have followed all the steps given here, https://github.com/plataformatec/devise, for overriding sessions controller

need help!

Comment: you can start by adding the code of the controller to the question.

Comment: starting with line 1, because thats where the error is being generated from.

Comment: You really need to include your entire sessions controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And there's the problem, constants in Ruby start with a capital letter.

Class names in Ruby are constants, and must start with a capital letter.

Change `users::SessionsController` to `Users::SessionsController`.